# check a calendar for duplicates before creating an event

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

I want to check a calendar for duplicates before creating an event. I took inspiration [here](https://techyesplease.com/code/google-calendar-reservation-approval-system/) and check the number of events in the period by

```
var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(request.date, request.endTime);
```

If conflicts is < 1 or title is different, I assume there is no existing duplicate.
Somehow my FOR loop condition is defined badly, it gets stuck in the first row. (I am still novice, bear with me please...)

The submission data:

```
// Create an object from user submission
function Submission(SheetByName, row){
  this.timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  this.anrede = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  this.name = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  this.nachname = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();  
  this.arrivalDate = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  this.deptDate = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  return this;
}
```

The function:

```
function updateCalendarsTest(request,row){
  //check for duplicate
  var intCal = 
  
 CalendarApp.getCalendarById('p*************0s@group.calendar.google.com');
  //check duplicates
  var duplicateExists;
  var conflictingEvents = intCal.getEvents(request.arrivalDate, 
  request.deptDate,{search: 'Gastkommentar:'});
  if (conflictingEvents.length < 1) {
    duplicateExists = false;}
  else {
   for (var i = 0; i = conflictingEvents.length; i++) { 
       if  ((conflictingEvents[i].getTitle()) == (request.bookID)) 
       {duplicateExists = true;} 
       break;
       }  
      }
   if (!duplicateExists ){    
     //create events
     var intEvent = intCal.createEvent(
     request.bookID,
     request.arrivalDate,
     request.deptDate,
     {description: request.intCalDescription}
     )
     sheet.getRange(row, 36).setValue("event created ");
     }
     else {ss.toast('duplicate Event!');} 
}
```

Calling Function:

```
function main(){
  var SheetByName = '*****';
  var now = new Date();
  for (var row = 4; row <= lastRow; row++) {
            updateCalendarsTest(request,row);
  }
   ss.toast('updated');
}
```

error log:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTitle' of undefined
at updateCalendarsTest(Code:246:35)
at main(Code:337:13)

What I tried:

- I suspected the FOR loop to need another start value, but for both
  i=0 and i=1 there is the same result.
- I suspected the
  conflictingEvents to be rather an array of calendars than of events,
  but could not resolve that by myself.
- Thanks to Jose's comment (thanks!) I rewrote the FOR loop to take care of empty arrays of events like this:

  if (conflictingEvents.length < 1) {
  duplicateExists = false;}
  else {

Comment: What do you mean by `There is no error log, but main keeps running when it is within the first row of data.`? Is it related to ` it gets stuck in the first row`? If so, how do you know it's stuck? As I can see in your code there's no reason for that to happen unless [Toast](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg) blocks the flow. In any case can you please specify where are you running this script (i.e. editor)?

Comment: Hi Jose, running in GAS editor, and I now also tried to remove the toast-command, but no effect.

Comment: By seeing the TypeError **Cannot read property 'getTitle' of undefined** it means `var conflictingEvents = intCal.getEvents(...{search: 'Gastkommentar:'})` returns an empty array rather than a CalendarEvent[] with at least 1 item. This might be due to parameter **search** inside the object passed as third parameter as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime,-options) says that it'll search for the whole text not just a regex-like text or this issue might be due to missing events. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Thanks to Jose's comment (thanks!) I rewrote the FOR loop to take care of empty arrays of events with an IF condition before the FOR. But I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

The FOR Loop had 2 failures:

```
for (var i = 0; i = conflictingEvents.length; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0; i <= conflictingEvents.length-1; i++) {
```

As the event array starts with event[0], and the property .length is the event count starting from 1, the end of the loop should be decreased by 1.

Another failure of the loop condition: <= instead of = .